# Como restar 2 listas en python? y posteriormente agregarla a una totalmente nueva

Tags: python, lista

Buen dia

Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy aprendiendo a programar en python y tengo una duda, ocupo restar 2 listas en python y agregarlas a una totalmente nueva, pero solo me arroja de vuelta una lista vacia, pueden ayudarme por favor este es el codigo.

```
def input_list():
    y = []
    flag = int(input("Please provide the size of the list"))
    for i in range(1, flag):
        a = int(input("Please provide a list element"))
        y.append(a)
        b = y
    new = sorted(b)
    print(new)
    new_list = []
    for i in range(int(new_list)):
        new_list[i] = new[i] - y[i]
    print(new_list)

input_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Después de declarar **new_list** intentas recorrer sus elementos pero como es una lista vacía el ciclo **for** no hace nada, en lugar de eso deberías recorrer la lista de elementos que introdujeron.

```py
def input_list():
    y = []
    n = int(input("Please provide the size of the list"))
    for i in range(n): 
        a = int(input("Please provide a list element"))
        y.append(a)

    print(y)

    s = sorted(y)
    print(s)

    new_list = []
    for a, b in zip(s, y):
        new_list.append(a - b)

    print(new_list)

input_list()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos errores en tu código, el más visible es el uso de `int(new_list)` este método se usa para convertir, por ejemplo un string a un entero `int("1")` siempre que sea posible de lo contrario retornara error, como sucede en tu caso puesto que intentar convertir una lista en un número entero no es posible.

El segundo error, que es la razón que te devuelve una lista vacía es porque `new_list` no tiene ningún elemento por lo cual cuando ejecutes `for i in range(len(new_list)):` esto no arrojara nada dado que `len(new_list)` es 0.

Te paso el código con algunas correcciones:

```
def input_list():
    lista = []

    #si son numeros lo acepta, de lo contrario muestra un mensaje
    try:
        flag = int(input("Please provide the size of the list: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(u"Debes ingresar números")
        return 0
    else:

        #todo en el try salio bien, procedemos
        for i in range(1, flag):
            a = input("Please provide a list element: ")
            if a.isdigit():#si lo que ingresaron es un numero, lo agregamos
                lista.append(int(a))
                b = lista

        #si la lista tiene elementos, entonces restamos
        if lista:
            otra_lista = sorted(b)
            nueva_lista = []
            new_list = []

            for i in range(len(otra_lista)):
                new_list.append(otra_lista[i] - lista[i])


            print(new_list, lista, otra_lista)

input_list()
```

Hazme saber cualquier duda.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda sigo mejorando.